# Sklearn Cross validate returning NaN with SVC model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm, cross-validation

I am using `cross_validate` from Sklearn and it is working fine for multiple models such as GaussianNB, RandomForestClassifier, KNeighborsClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier and XGBClassifier but when using it with SVC it returns `nan`. Here's my code and the things I've tried.

```
models = [('GaussianNB', GaussianNB()), ('RandomForest', RandomForestClassifier()), ('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()), 
          ('SVM', SVC()), ('GradientBoosting', GradientBoostingClassifier()), ('XGB', XGBClassifier(eval_metric='mlogloss'))]
scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted', 'roc_auc_ovr_weighted']

for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(model, X_train, y_train.values, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    this_df = pd.DataFrame(cv_results)
    this_df['model'] = name
    dfs.append(this_df)
final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

The output is shown in the picture below, you can see values for all models but SVC.

I have tried single code like this and it outputs a value but not when in the `cross_validate`

```
>>> model_selection.cross_val_score(SVC(), X_train, y_train.values, cv=kfold, scoring='recall_weighted')
array([0.58930041, 0.59506173, 0.59060956, 0.61532125, 0.62685338])
```

I've tried converting to dataframe but same result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue you need to enable `probability=True` in the model.
It seems that Sklearn carries any error for all the scores. Probability is needed for `roc_auc_ovr_weighted`